# Перегрузка оператора ==

Tags: c++

Встречал два вида записи перегрузки оператора ==:  
`bool operator == ( MyClass &a, MyClass &b )` и  
`bool operator ==(const MyClass &a)`.
  В чем разница в использовании? И как проводить сравнение во втором случае?

Comment: @Abyx, ну не близко даже. Человек не понимает сути этой перегрузки.

Comment: @Abyx, ну там оно как-бы между делом, тематика вопроса всё же другая. Мне кажется, что из того ответа автор не извлечёт ответ на свой.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Перегрузить оператор `==` можно двумя способами по отношению к их расположению:

- в классе
- вне класса

При перегрузке в классе первый `MyClass` не надо, так как в данном методе есть указатель this, который неявно передаётся первым параметром в метод: - то есть компилятор основываясь на this "якобы" вызовет `bool operator == ( MyClass &a, MyClass &b )`.

---

Отмечу так же, что согласно рекомендации Страуструпа операторы, которые можно перегрузить, что в классе, что вне и они не меняют состояние объекта следует перегружать всё же вне класса.

---

Итого возможные перегрузки оператора `==`:
(вне класса)`bool operator == ( const MyClass &a, const MyClass &b )`
(в классе)`bool operator == ( const MyClass & right )`
(в классе)`bool operator == ( const MyClass & right ) const`

Comment: Переформулируйте, плиз, фразу "При перегрузке в классе первый...", у Вас там явно глагол пропущен.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A() : a(0) {}
    A(int a) : a(a) {}
    bool operator == (const A &rhs) const { cout << "A==" << endl; return this->a == rhs.a; }
private:
    int a;
};

class B
{
    friend bool operator == (const B &lhs, const B &rhs);
public:
    B() : a(0) {}
    B(int a) : a(a) {}
private:
    int a;
};
bool operator == (const B &lhs, const B &rhs) { cout << "B==" << endl; return lhs.a == rhs.a; }

int main()
{
    A a1; A a2(1);
    B b1; B b2(0);
    cout << (a1 == a2) << endl; // OK
    cout << (b1 == b2) << endl; // OK также
    cout << (b1 == 1) << endl; // OK, 1 --> B(1)
    cout << (1 == b1) << endl; // OK, 1 --> B(1) тоже
    cout << (a1 == 0) << endl; // OK, 0 --> A(0)
    // cout << (1 == a2) << endl; --> error: no match for operator==(int, A)
    return 0;
}
```

Разница заключается в возможности неявного приведения типов для обоих сторон сравнения для функции (оператора) - не члена класса.